# How to overlay two menus over Google Maps, one in each side of the screen?

Tags: css, google-maps, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm building this PWA using Vue.js with Vuetify.js and I want to put 2 buttons over Google Maps: One in the left side of the screen to open the navigation drawer and one in the right side of the screen to open user info dropdown.

I was able to put the left one where I want, but I am unable to understand how to put the user icon in the right side.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: What I did so far]

This is what I was expecting:

[image: What I was expecting]

My template looks something like this:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <v-row align-content="center">
    <v-icon size="30" @click="drawer = !drawer">mdi-menu</v-icon>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-avatar color="teal" size="30">
      <v-icon dark>mdi-account</v-icon>
    </v-avatar>
  </v-row>
</div>
<div id="g-map"></div>
```

And My style looks like this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#g-map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.overlay {
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

I tried adding `right: 20px;` and `float: right;` to `<v-avatar>`, but it just get worst.

How can I fix that with Vuetify.js or css?

**EDIT:**

How it looks with with `<v-toolbar>`:

[image: With v-toolbar]

Both icons are in the right positions on each side of the screen, but it's not overlaying Google Maps as my expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it adding a second div and a second class. It was pretty obvious if I think about it.

```
<div class="overlayLeft">
  <v-icon size="30" @click="drawer = !drawer">mdi-menu</v-icon>
</div>
<div class="overlayRight">
  <v-avatar color="teal" size="30">
    <v-icon dark>mdi-account</v-icon>
  </v-avatar>
</div>
<div id="g-map"></div>
```

And in my styles:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#g-map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.overlayLeft {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.overlayRight {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

This is how it's looking now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a toolbar? You need to wrap it in v-toolbar 
doc:https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars

```
<v-toolbar prominent extended>
  <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon> 
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-btn icon>
    <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-toolbar>
```

Apart from that, all v-row should be wrapped under v-container. v-col should be the only direct child of v-row

```
<v-container>
 <v-row>
   <v-col>
   </v-col>
 </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Comment: I can't overlay Google Maps if I use the toolbar. I edited my question with the result of using toolbar.